# How to connect to a Hyper-V guest, from an other, remote PC

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop, virtualization, windows-server-2008

I have installed a Windows Server 2008R2 SP1 Datacenter edition, and I have added the Hyper-V role, with RemoteFX.

Installed a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with SP1. Updated the additions, enabled RemoteFX. But... how do I reach the guest?

Okay that I have to enable remote desktop. Did so. Even changed the port on the guest. But how would one reach it from outside? Is there a NAT configuration applet, application somewhere, where I should forward it's port to the outer network?

Comment: We'll need more info... How did you set up the Hyper-V networking?  Is the guest able to surf the Internet (etc.)?

Comment: Yes, it can reach the outer network without problem. (External if I remember correctly.) I've also installed every update on the guest.

Comment: What I don't get is: How would even an outside computer would reach the inner guest? I mean... in VMWare, you have a "Network Editor" application, where you can set up the NAT. Like forwarding out the default RDP port. But how to do the same in Windows Server / Hyper-V?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2010/06/06/how-to-configure-remote-desktop-to-hyper-v-guest-virtual-machines.aspx | Here, he installs an Internal network card in Hyper-V, for the guest. Do I really need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the physical host's NIC to [bridged mode(external)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/virtualmachingmgrhyperv/thread/718269b2-f17d-49d9-ae8d-6a585ed264be/) will allow you to accomplish this. Afterwards, just make sure that:

1. RDP is enabled on the guest, and the necessary firewall ports are open.
2. The Guest OS has an IP on the physical network (same subnet as host)
3. The IP of the guest is set as STATIC
4. You have some sort of [port-forwarder](http://portforward.com/) rule on the router (since you're talking about from outside the network) that, say, detects the request for RDP on 3390, and forwards it to your workstation's IP.

With those requirements met, you should be able to RDP in no problem.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know, that it will request a very new IP, with a brand new MAC. It's working now. (Now I have to fix up RemoteFX, since it's really terrible at the moment.)

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer did help you out, make sure you hit that little green checkmark. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, got carried away with the testing. Well.. I've got a GTX video card, and the remote desktop connection is just way too slow. I thought I would be able to play games or something. But it's just not possible.

Comment: Yea, probably not. Especially if the client is virtualized. The whole systemic timing a virtual machine is a little different than a physical machine. RemoteFX is best utilized serving apps like Office, not Crysis 2. This blog post, however, seems to indicate that it CAN be done, Assuming the server is at SP1, the workstation is at SP1, and the connecting machine is at SP1 (RemoteFX doesnt work on anything less), and that you have a RemoteFX-certified graphics card inside the server.  http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1561056

Comment: Guess my card is not RemoteFX compatible. :( Well, it was a good experience. Thanks for the fast answer. It helped me out.